# Dictionary is allowing me to insert duplicate keys

Tags: c#, dictionary

I've create some classes, so that I can have a dictionary with a pair as a key

```
public class RouteKey
{
    public Equip Equipment { get; set; }
    public Destiny Destiny { get; set; }

    public RouteKey() { }
    public RouteKey(Equip Equipment, Destiny Destiny) {
        this.Equipment = Equipment;
        this.Destiny = Destiny;
    }
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) return false;

    if (this.GetType() != obj.GetType()) return false;

    RouteKey rk = (RouteKey)obj;

    // use this pattern to compare reference members
    if (!Object.Equals(Equipment, rk.Equipment)) return false;

    // use this pattern to compare value members
    if (!Destiny.Equals(rk.Destiny)) return false;

    return true;        
}

public class RouteValue
{
    public string Endpoint { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public RouteValue() { }
    public RouteValue(string Endpoint, bool Enabled) {
        this.Endpoint = Endpoint;
        this.Enabled = Enabled;
    }
}

public Dictionary<RouteKey, RouteValue> Routes;
```

My problem is that I'm able to run this code without errors...

```
RouteKey rk1 = new RouteKey(Equip.SpaceShip, Destiny.sun);
RouteKey rk2 = new RouteKey(Equip.SpaceShip, Destiny.sun);
RouteKey rk3 = new RouteKey(Equip.Boat, Destiny.hell);

RouteValue rv1 = new RouteValue("rv1", true);
RouteValue rv2 = new RouteValue("rv2", false);
RouteValue rv3 = new RouteValue("rv3", true);

Routes.Add(rk1, rv1);
Routes.Add(rk3, rv3);
Routes.Add(rk2, rv2);
```

I've tried adding the equals method to the RouteKey class, but in debug I can see the code never passes by that method.

What can I do to have the dictionary to behave as expected?

Comment: public Dictionary<Equip, RouteValue> Routes;

Comment: Don't forget to override the `GetHashCode` method as well.

Comment: where is the duplicate you expect to cause this to fail?  I don't see it.

Comment: Did u override also the `Gethashcode`?
[another post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overriden-in-c

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: You have to look at the OP's interesting `Equals` method to fathom that.

Comment: @leppie Huh? Does IDictionary use `Equals()`?  Wouldn't it need to use the hashcode?  EDIT: Ah, I see, that was the answers as stated below.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: You can assert that by implementing `GetHashCode` as `return 0;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `RouteKey` needs to override the [`GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) method in such a way that hash codes of equal `RouteKey` instances are also equal (but not necessarily the other way around).

Answer (score 3):

You have only overridden `Equals()` in your `RoutKey` class.

You should also override `GetHashCode()` - this is what the `Dictionary` will be using for testing for equality.

When overriding `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`, you should also consider overriding the `==` and `!=` operators.

I suggest reading [Guidelines for Overriding Equals() and Operator == (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

For the RouteKey class you need to override the GetHashCode() method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx

Also you can check this SO question: [When do we do GetHashCode() for a Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407380/when-do-we-do-gethashcode-for-a-dictionary)