# KeyNotFoundException in filled dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, compare, keynotfoundexception

I am trying to modify value in dictionary, but the compiler throws `KeyNotFoundException`. I'm sure, I declared that key in dictionary, because I am calling `GenerateEmptyChunks()` method, which fills dictionary with chunks with key of their position and values are empty for level generator. I've checked debugger and `Chunks` dictionary object is correctly filled with keys and values. Is it caused by my unworking `CompareTo` method? If yes, how I have modify `CompareTo` method to return right values?

```
public Dictionary<WPoint, WChunk> Chunks = new Dictionary<WPoint, WChunk>();
```

*GenerateEmptyChunks()* method:

```
public void GenerateEmptyChunks(int Xcount, int Ycount)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x <= Xcount; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= Ycount; y++)
            {
                this.Chunks.Add(new WPoint(x, y), new WChunk(x, y));
            }
        }
    }
```

*AddBlock()* method which is called by level generator for each tile:

```
public void AddBlock(WPoint location, int data)
    {
        this.Chunks[location.GetChunk()].AddTile(new WTile(location, data));
    }
```

*WChunk* object:

```
public class WChunk
    {
        public int ChunkX;
        public int ChunkY;
        public SortedDictionary<WPoint, WTile> Tiles = new SortedDictionary<WPoint, WTile>();

        public WChunk(int posX, int posY)
        {
            ChunkX = posX;
            ChunkY = posY;
        }

        public void AddTile(WTile tile)
        {
            Tiles.Add(tile.GetLocation(), tile);
        }
    }
```

*WPoint* object:

```
public class WPoint : IComparable
    {
        public float X;
        public float Y;

        public WPoint(float x, float y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public WPoint GetChunk()
        {
            //Oprava pre bloky mensie ako (1,1)
            if (X <= 16 && Y <= 16)
            {
                return new WPoint(0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                double pX = (double)(X / 16);
                double pY = (double)(Y / 16);
                return new WPoint((int)Math.Floor(pX), (int)Math.Floor(pY));
            }
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            WPoint point2 = (WPoint)obj;
            if (point2.X == this.X && point2.Y == this.Y)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (point2.X >= this.X && point2.Y >= this.Y)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
}
```

Any ideas why is compiler rejecting keys, when they are in dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You have not overridden GetHashCode.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is using the GetHashCode and Equals for key comparisons, so implementing the IComparable interface is not enough. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407380/when-do-we-do-gethashcode-for-a-dictionary), that's exactly what you need.